# Authenticator.setdefault working in Java but not in Android (giving 401 error)

Tags: java, android, authentication, jsoup

I'm trying to read from a local network URL (using GET). But, the server (router in this case) asks for a username/password as below:
[image]

I'm using below code for basic http authentication:

```
Authenticator.setDefault( new Authenticator() {
                      @Override protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication ("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
                      }
                    });

                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://192.168.0.100:5000/location_list.cgi?action=load").ignoreHttpErrors(isRestricted()).get();
                    System.out.println(doc);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and it is working fine when run as a Java Application. But, in Android application, it gives **401 UnAuthorized** error code.

I've even tried
**Authentication: basic ["admin:admin".toBASE64encoding]** but the problem is same. Kindly help.

Comment: btw not all java library support android

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Thanks for reply. Anyhow, can you suggest something? I really need to get it working by today.

Comment: i suggest you using webservice. read the content using service (java or php). and sent it back to your android

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Thanks a lot. I was thinking the same. But, i'm confused as to where i would host my service since the router is in local network.

Comment: host it in your local too. you've said that your code is working fine when run as java application.

Answer (score 0):

my friend, I have met the same problem, finally I found one solution:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
                GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(mCameraVideo.getCameraIP() + "tmpfs/auto.jpg");
                //int status = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
                UsernamePasswordCredentials upc = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(mCameraVideo.getUserName(), mCameraVideo.getPassword());
                AuthScope as = new AuthScope(mCameraVideo.getHost(), mCameraVideo.getPort(), "");
                client.getState().setCredentials(as, upc);
                int status = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
                // getMethod.releaseConnection();
```

See also:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9579